# Making an option false by default

Tags: ruby

This is a common way to set a default in Ruby:

```
class QuietByDefault
  def initialize(opts = {})
    @verbose = opts[:verbose]
  end
end
```

This is an easy **trap** to fall into:

```
class VerboseNoMatterWhat
  def initialize(opts = {})
    @verbose = opts[:verbose] || true
  end
end
```

This is a correct way to do it:

```
class VerboseByDefault
  def initialize(opts = {})
    @verbose = opts.include?(:verbose) ? opts[:verbose] : true
  end
end
```

What is the best / cleanest way to code `VerboseByDefault`? (I could factor it out, of course.)

What pattern is widely used, if any, in Ruby code in general? Does ActiveSupport have a pattern for this? (Minimal is better -- I don't need a full command line option parser.)

Ranting P.S.: I don't like the asymmetry between code that handles a default `true` vs. code that handles a default `false` option. A pattern that makes changing between the two -- without causing bugs -- would be a good thing to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to do it is by using the second argument to Hash#fetch

```
class VerboseByDefault
  def initialize(opts = {})
    @verbose = opts.fetch(:verbose, true)
  end
end
```

For complex defaults, fetch can also take a block, which is executed if the value isn't in the hash.  See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch

Comment: Very nice! I *may* have seen this before, but I didn't remember it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've commonly seen it as setting all your defaults, and then merging them with the opts. such as..

```
def initialize(opts = {})
  @options = { :verbose => false, :foo => 42 } 
  @options.merge!(opts)
  # ...
end
```

This way all of your options are set in one place and you just merge the user supplied ones.

Comment: I like the idea of starting with defaults and merging in user supplied options, but you've got a bug in how you scope `@options`! Watch your `self`. :)

Comment: oh sorry it wasn't meant as a complete solution :)  I'll edit it and put it inside...

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge'
class VerboseByDefault
  DEFAULTS = { verbose: true }
  def initialize(opts = {})
    opts.reverse_merge!(DEFAULTS)
    @verbose = opts[:verbose]
  end
end
```

This isn't only a little cleaner just for one option, but it becomes way better if you have more options. Also, it uses the same pattern for `true` and `false`.